# Writing a fat-client with self-hosting WCF project for windows using visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, self-hosting, servicehost

I have been researching this for days without success. I have a visual studio 2010 solution with multiple projects. I am trying to create a fat client in a managed application using self-hosting of a WCF Service Application. I am moving the application to run on a windows 8 machine that does **NOT** have visual studio installed.

On the development machine, all works well **until** I try to create a ServiceHost for the target machine. When I try to add a ServiceHost , the development machine bombs with:

```
"HTTP could not register URL http://+:24324/DataService.svc/. Your process does not 
have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 
for details)."
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help is *really* appreciated. Thanks.

In the client app.config, I have:

```
  <client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:24324/DataService.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" 
            contract="DataService.INovaDataService" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService"/>
</client>
```

In the client Window constructor for the client project, I have:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:24324/DataService.svc");
static ServiceHost host;

 ***Note: In the WCF project itself, "NovaDatServiceClient" is defined  as "NovaDataService"

        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(NovaDataServiceClient), baseAddress);   

        host.Open();    <--*ERROR --HTTP could not register 
          URL http://+:24324/DataService.svc/. Your process does not have access rights to this
         namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details)."}
```

In the Web.config for the WCF Service Application, I have:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are running into Port Reservation Permissions issues. The application is trying to reserve the TCP port but the user its running as lacks the rights to do so. This link explains the concept and the command lines you need to run to grant your application user port reservation permissions,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does this apply to the development machine under visual studio or just the target machine? Thanks.

Comment: Just the target machine

Comment: Umm...Any suggestions on how to debug this on the development machine...The automatic initialization of ASP.net during debugging is binding to the port preventing host.open() from binding for the servicehost :(

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:24324/ user=DOMAIN\user
```

Comment: I ran your suggestion in the cmd on the development machine. Now while debugging, the error is "HTTP could not register URL.. because TCP port 24324 is being used by another application." Help!?

Comment: Well, yes, I believe the solution is in the error message. This site tells you how to find out which application is using the 24324 port. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/ You must then either close that program, or change your WCF server port to one that is not already in use on the target.

Comment: @PhillipH I'm pretty sure it's visual studio itself that is binding to the port during the debug session before I can call host.open() So I can't put servicehost in the code??

Comment: @PhillipH Found it. F4 on the WCF project, then set ASP.net dev to false. Thanks.